# Do questions that are voted up influence other users to vote that question up?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

I feel that if a question has at least 1 vote, it will influence more people to vote it up regardless if it deserves to be voted up. Is this okay?

Comment: Yeah, this is *sometimes* true. But everyone is voting voluntary, so nobody can do anything against this.

Comment: [I can't see anything that obviously supports this idea in the data](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60889/question-scores). Though maybe someone more adept at statistics than me might be able to determine some statistical anomaly.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the person viewing the upvote and how strong their urge to conform with the community is. I think this is actually quite rare. I never do this at all. I actually tend to evaluate the question for its content and *then* look at the upvote count to determine if it deserves another upvote based on what it provides. If it already has 3 upvotes and I feel it only really deserves 3 upvotes, then I'll just leave it alone. Of course, it's a personal evaluation that isn't really based on anything in particular.

Some users, however, see the big 10 and immediately go "oh, this is popular, I better vote it up too" without really reading the question. There are two sides to the scale here, and as with any scale, the entire community is widely spread across it.

To answer your question: **yes** this does happen occasionally, but not nearly as often as people might want to believe.

Comment: I think this deserves more than 3 up votes, so I'll add one! ;-)